# How to calculate the normalized magnitude of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a set of complex numbers which is used to create an image. According to the documentation, each pixel is calculated using the normalized magnitude in decibel scale of the complex number.

How can I calculate the normalized magnitude and obtain a single value (with no imaginary part)?

Thank you.

Comment: You might get a better response in Computer Science.

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of $z_n$ complex numbers with $n$ from $1$ to $N$. $n$ might be a set of two indices in case of an image. The magnitude of $z_n=\Re z_n+i\Im z_n$ is given by $|z_n|=\sqrt{\Re^2z_n+\Im^2z_n}$. The normalizes magnitude is given by $I_n=\frac{|z_n|}{max(|z_j|)}$. In decibels you just need to use $10\log_{10}I_n$.

In a program, do the following steps:

1. Calculate the magnitude of all complex numbers
2. Find the maximum of these magnitudes
3. Divide all magnitudes by the maximum value
4. Take the logarithm base 10, and then multiply by 10.